# How to load an image dynamically to a report?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Is there a way to load an image dynamically to a report based on image path.
The image file name is stored in database.

FYI. I'm using CrystalReport designer embedded with VS.NET 2005.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128239/dynamically-change-an-image-in-a-crystal-report-at-runtime/572208#572208

Answer (score 0):

Insert an OLE object, right click on it and select Format Object, and create a formula for it location in the Graphic Location, you should be able to reference your database fields to build the path to the location.