# pass image path as parameter to image in crystal report c#

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i have crystal report contain image, i want to pass the path of image vi parameter, here is c# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string ImagePath = "D:/xx.png";
                QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(textBox1.Text, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
                Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
                qrCodeImage.Save(ImagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                if (!File.Exists(ImagePath))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
                    return;
                }
                Report1 r = new Report1();
                DataSet1 d = new DataSet1();
                r.SetDataSource(d);
                
              // byte[] data= ImageToByteArray(qrCodeImage);
                r.SetParameterValue("PathOfQRCodeImage", ImagePath);
                
                Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
                f.ShowDialog();
       
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }
```

i click on Image in crystal report > format object > picture > graphic location and i put this formula as seen here :
[image]
the problem is that the image not changed to image i send vi parameter, here is screenshot:
[image]
i hope you help to solve this problem, please notes i have to send image path vi parameter. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You want to google for "crystal reports dynamic images". Answers include [exposing the byte[] property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128239/dynamically-change-an-image-in-a-crystal-report-at-runtime) for the report, using a [conditional formula](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/), and [using an image path in your database](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30860/How-to-dynamically-load-images-in-Crystal-Reports).